# Ovewrite vs delete

Tags: windows, filesystems

I want to ask if anyone knows the difference between deleting a file and then copying new version in the same directory vs overwriting old file with new file. Does overwrite mean correcting the bits of the old file or it also deletes the old file before applying the new one?

Comment: There is little practical difference. If overwrite means a larger file (common), it will likely get moved to a new location, which is much the same as delete and write new. Overwrite just makes a complete new version of the existing file.

Answer (score 3):

When you copy a file to a new location and a file already exists on this location, you can get a question whether or not you want to overwrite or rename or cancel the operation.

Depending on what program you use, the action for overwrite can be different. In case of windows Explorer, when you choose overwrite, it will first delete the old file entirely, then copy the new file entirely. The file deleted is a hard delete though, as if you pressed shift-delete rather than just shift. Its not moved to the recycle-bin and thus cannot be restored later. Of course, if you hard-deleted the file before copying the new file back in place, that file cannot be restored either, and there's no difference then.

Why doesn't it copy only the necessary bits? Because comparing the file bit by bit to see if it needs to be altered is taking more time than to just delete and copy the whole file over.

Comment: One substantial difference between the methods is that in case of overwriting, the original file isn't moved to recycle bin, so it's more difficult to restore

Comment: Very good point @MátéJuhász I'll edit my answer accordingly. :) Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Typically files are made of storage blocks on disk. When you copy a file, OS will duplicate the block and when the duplication is done will create and indication in file system table that the clone is ready.

When you delete a file, it still remains on disk, just the reference to the file in File system is removed. Files can be recovered by reading the magnetic platters on hard disk. Softwares like Recuva do that.

Now after when you delete a file, and a create a new file in the same name and extension the file is no actually "deleted". Now when purged, no way to recover that.

Windows or any OS will not allow you to keep same files (with same name and extension) in same directories. But you can keep it in a different directory.